# Questions' edit history label the original question as answered

Tags: bug, status-completed

If you look at a questions edit history the edits are labelled 'editted', which is fine but the original question is labelled 'answered', which is wrong.

For an example see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/1370/list the original question says 'answered 5 hours ago' above the questioners name. It hasn't been answered.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug indeed... should be **"asked"**

Answer (score 1):

Below is a screen shot, just to make this issue clear:

[image: loading ...]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's a common page for editing entries of any sort, be they questions or answers.  The question page allows you to edit the tags and the title as well as the text.  Apparently they forgot to change the "answered" to "asked"